# How to avoid "RXTX Warning: Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM0"

Tags: java

I'm using RXTXcomm.jar and librxtxSerial.so from the librxtx-java package on 64-Bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm getting the following warning every time I run my application on 64-Bit 1.6.0_45 JRE:

```
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM0
```

Is there a way to get rid of this annoying RXTX Warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add "sudo" at the front of your java execution.

```
sudo java -jar xxxxx.jar
```

As the lock file may need using "admin" right to delete.

Or you can maunally to delete the lock file before running the JAVA program.

```
sudo rm -f /var/lock/<name of lock file>
```